# spring boot tests - how to start embedded server before spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, integration-testing

When writing integration tests quite often there is a need to start some server (e.g. redis, zookeeper) on an ephemeral port and then pass the port as a property to Spring. The problem is that the actually used port is unknown before the server starts so it can't be passed via annotation:

```
@IntegrationTest(["redis.port=???"])
class RedisTest {
    @Before
    before(){
       int port = startRedis(
    }
}
```

What's the idiomatic way to achieve that? Ideally I'd like to put that into a junit rule.

Here's something that works for me, but does not look good (passing port via static variable):

```
@IntegrationTest(initializers=Initializer.class)
public class RedisTest {
    public static int port;

    public static class Initializer implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {
        public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx){
            port = startRedis()
            EnvironmentTestUtils.addEnvironment(ctx, "redisPort=" + port)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//set server.port=0 and then inject the actual (‘local’) port as a @Value

@WebIntegrationTest("server.port:0")    
public class RedisTest{

    @Autowired
    EmbeddedWebApplicationContext server;

    @Value("${local.server.port}")
    int port;    

}
```

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-embedded-servlet-containers.html#howto-discover-the-http-port-at-runtime

Comment: It is not relevant to the question... My problem is related to other servers in the environment, not http embedded in Spring Boot.